# How to declare(?) NSTimer function?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I want to use the following: 
class func sleepForTimeInterval(_ ti: NSTimeInterval)

 It is a NSTimer function that I found [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSThread_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSThread/sleepForTimeInterval:). I cant figure out how and where to declare the function. I want a 0.1s delay before executing another function.

Comment: Actually, if I were you I'd drop the whole thing. Just stick my `delay` function somewhere and call that: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24318861/341994

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something after 0.1, you can probably try this code:

```
double delayInSeconds = 0.1;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, delayInSeconds);
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    // do something after delay
});
```

For beginner, it's the best if you can go check out the documentation. Here is the link about NSTimer: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSTimer_Class/index.html

And I don't think you can do something like what you said by using `NSTimer`.